# How to use interpolation to set an attribute selector?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, typescript, angular

I have a String variable that holds a reference to an icon, which I want to bind in the HTML to show it, as an attribute selector.

---

### Code Snippet

***.html***

```
    <thumbnail {{ obj.getIcon() }}> </thumbnail>
```

***.ts***

```
    getIcon() {
        return "icon-obj" + this.id;
    }
```

---

### Output

```
    <thumbnail "icon-obj1"> </thumbnail>
```

---

### Desired Output

```
    <thumbnail icon-obj1> </thumbnail>
```

---

### *Known & Undesired alternative solution*

```
    <thumbnail class={{ obj.getIcon() }} > </thumbnail>
```

---

Basically, **the string quotes are screwing everything**. It works if I use a different type of selector, like I showed in the example above that outputs to `class="icon-obj1"`, but that's not the point.

So, any suggestion?
*Thanks for reading!*

Answer (score 2):

There is no way of doing this. For dynamically added attributes or classes no directives or components are created anyway - only for statically added element-, attribute-, and class-names.

For adding components dynamically use [DynamicComponentLoader](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html).
I don't know yet if this also works with directives though.